# jquery what is .on('scroll.cssAnimFunc') function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This site http://www.reveltonsuites.cz/why-choose-us/ has on scroll animation 
when I checked it's js file there's a function

```
win.on('scroll.cssAnimFunc', function(event) {

          allMods.each(function(el) {

            if (visible2($(this), true)) {
              $(this).addClass("come-in"); 
            } 
          });
```

I googled 'scroll.cssAnimFunc' but it shows no results

Comment: Maybe they wrote this for themselves, not a **Public** function.

Comment: Perhaps a name spaced event someone created?

Comment: That's a namespaced event: https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

Comment: Is it possible to see where it is defined?